# Sqlite3 добавляется мусор вместо строк

Tags: c++, sqlite, sqlite3

Не получается корректно вставить строки в таблицу с использованием шаблонов, пробую так:

```
template<typename ...Types>
void bind(sqlite3_stmt *stmt, Types ...arg)
{
    std::string arr[] = { arg... };

    size_t i = 1;
    for (auto &e: arr) {

        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, i, e.c_str(), -1, 0 );

        i++;
    }
}

template<typename ...Types>
void exec(std::string sqlCmd, Types ...arg)
{
    sqlite3 *handle;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    sqlite3_open("test.db", &handle);
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(handle, sqlCmd.c_str(), -1, &stmt, 0);

    bind(stmt, arg...);
    sqlite3_step(stmt);
}

int main()
{
    exec("CREATE TABLE test_table (first_col TEXT, second_col TEXT, third_col TEXT);");

    exec("INSERT INTO test_table (first_col, second_col, third_col) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? )",
        "val_1",
        "val_2",
        "val_3");
}
```

После выполнения в базу строки добавляются в таком виде(какой-то мусор):

```
first_col   second_col  third_col 
----------  ----------  ----------
��                      val_3    
�z�x�                     val_3 
�����                      val_3
```

Если не выносить код в отдельную функцию bind, все работает нормально. Почему? Я не правильно передаю шаблон переменной длины?
Также если внутри bind объявить `const char* arr[]`вместо `std::string arr[]`, то все работает нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас локальная переменная в функции `bind` уничтожается после выхода из функции:

```
std::string arr[] = { arg... };
```

Могу посоветовать переписать так:

```
void bind(sqlite3_stmt *stmt, std::vector<std::string>& arr) // НЕ-const, чтобы временный объект не передать случайно
{
    size_t i = 1;
    for (auto &e: arr) {

        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, i, e.c_str(), -1, 0 );

        i++;
    }
}

template<typename ...Types>
void exec(std::string sqlCmd, Types ...arg)
{
    sqlite3 *handle;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    sqlite3_open("test.db", &handle);
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(handle, sqlCmd.c_str(), -1, &stmt, 0);

    std::vector<std::string> arr{ arg... };
    bind(stmt, arr);
    sqlite3_step(stmt);
}
```

Comment: можно оставить всё как было и задать SQLITE_TRANSIENT последним параметром.